# preflight did not succeed

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, cors

I'm working with my first web application. I have a Java server app using Jersey for a RESTful API, and I have a JavaScript (jQuery) driven client application. I'm an experienced Java developer, but this is my first time working with JavaScript and CORS in general.

So, first, here is the filter that is adding CORS headers to all responses coming through my server. I've run the application in debug mode, I know this filter is executing properly.

```
@Provider
public class CrossOriginHeaderFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter{

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

        MultivaluedMap<String,Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); //TODO specify the origin here
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*"); //TODO figure out what headers to allow
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

    }
}
```

And here is the jQuery Ajax call I'm using to call the server:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/orgapi/auth",
                type: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Request-Method": "POST"
                },
                crossOrigin: true,
                data: jsonMsg,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(){
                    alert("Login successful");
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    alert(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

I've been reading all I can find about CORS and all of this, and I'm stuck. I don't know what I am doing wrong, but I'm willing to bet I'm configuring something wrong with my headers.

Comment: This looks like you're doing everything right. I would open up devtools, go to the network tab, and look at the actual headers that you're getting back from the OPTIONS request. Maybe they're not getting sent for some reason.

Comment: What is the error reported on browser console for this particular request?